# MS Excel - assigning recurring weeks that reset every month

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365, date-time, date, automatic-update

I have a set of dates say in column A and want to associate custom week numbers that reset after every 5 weeks.

So for example, the week counting starts from 27/09/21 (Monday) and will end on 31/10/21 (Sunday) making it 5 weeks. For dates after 31st of October, I’d want to reset the week number to 1 and count up to 5 again. Similarly, for dates before 27th of September, the week numbers should decrease from 5 to 1 and reset again.

I’ve been trying to play around with WeekNum() for hours but haven’t managed to figure out a way to do this. Is there a way to dynamically assign custom recurring week numbers like that?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given:

- A column with a list of Mondays
- A `Week_1` representing any week 1 in that sequence
- you can use the formula in the first cell in the sequence:

  ```
   =MOD(SEQUENCE(COUNT(myDates),,(A2-Week_1)/7,1),5)+1
  ```
- The results will `SPILL` down the `myDates` column

[image]

If your list of dates includes EVERY date sequentially, then, in the cell adjacent to the first date, you can enter:

```
=MOD(INT((myDates-Week_1)/7),5)+1
```

and the results will spill down:

[image]